# Websocket client is not calling on_message_callback() function when it receives a message from server

Tags: tornado

I want a server and a client to communicate to each other.

Client side:

```python
@gen.coroutine
def connect(self):
    print("trying to connect")
    try:
        self.ws = yield websocket_connect(self.url, connect_timeout=99999, on_message_callback=on_message)
    except Exception as e:
        print("connection error : {}".format(e))

       print("connected")
```

But here there is no call of on_message whenever its server send message. Do you have any idea of these?

Comment: Your code looks alright. Does a function named `on_message` exist? Or did you mean `self.on_message`? Are you sure server is sending messages?

Comment: I should have mentioned about it. Yes I have one which is declared out of the class

Comment: OK. There is nothing wrong with the code sample you posted.  I can think of two reasons for your code not working - 1) You forgot to start the `IOLoop`. 2) The server is not sending messages.

Comment: @xyres Thanks for answer. In client side, both are checked. I uploaded my source code here  github.com/verystrongjoe/a3c-sketch Could you check for me? You can see this source code globalAgent.py for server and localAgent.py for client!!

Comment: I took a look at the source. Are you trying to get message from websocket in [lines 158-168 in localAgent.py](https://github.com/verystrongjoe/a3c-sketch/blob/master/cartpole/localAgent.py#L158-L168)?

Comment: @xyres Thanks for answering. Yes I have been suffering under this problem.Did you notice any problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I took a look at the source code. I can't pinpoint the problem as I don't 
understand what most of it is doing.

But I noticed certain things that I think might be causing the problems. For 
example [this code block](https://github.com/verystrongjoe/a3c-sketch/blob/master/cartpole/localAgent.py#L158-L168):

```python
response = yield self.ws.read_message(callback=self.cb_receive_weight)

...

if response.done() :
```

This will raise an error. `response` is not a future, but the actual websocket 
message string. So, it will raise an AttributeError that it doesn't have a `done()` method.

Second, `callback=self.cb_receive_weight` this will call the `cd_receive_weight` 
method with a future, not the message. So, that won't work.

I think things are not working as expected is maybe because you're mixing `yield` 
and callbacks.

---

Remember, `yield object` will automatically call `object.result()`. Consider:

```python
response = yield self.ws.read_message()
```

Above, `ws.read_message()` returns a Future, but `yield`, will wait until the Future 
has a result. When the Future gets resolved, `yield` will call its `result()` method. 
And `response` will be equal to that result.

You don't really need to use callbacks if you're using `yield`. I'd suggest not 
using callback style of coding at all. Just avoid them and use coroutines (`yield`)
where possible.

The code will be shorter and much more organised.

Example:

```python
@gen.coroutine
def connect(self):
    self.ws = yield websocket_connect(url)

    self.run()

...

@gen.coroutine
def get_weight_from_global_network(self):

    while True:
        response = yield self.ws.read_message()

        # do something with the response

        self.cb_recieve_weight(weight=response)
```

Although, I can't say if this will solve your problem.

Comment: thanks so much. actually I found out that I need to configure for two coroutines to run in parallel.  Maybe your answer is similar as mine. I will try and give feedback to you. Thanks again for concerning my problem!!